# Sort a data frame and keep the main col

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this

```
   name stock_11 stock_1 stock_2
    main1 0       4        1
    main2 2       2        3
    main3 4       4        8
    main4 7       7        3
```

And I would like to short the df based on the name of every column but keep first the column "name". For the other col names it is column "stock_"

The output result I try to have is this:

```
name stock_1 stock_2 stock_11
main1 4        1       0
main2 2        3       2
main3 4        8       4
main4 7        3       7
```

I tried this but it sorts all names:

```
df[ , order(names(df))]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a lot of columns

```
df[, c(1, order(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]+", "", names(df)[-1]))) + 1)]

   name stock_1 stock_2 stock_11
1 main1       4       1        0
2 main2       2       3        2
3 main3       4       8        4
4 main4       7       3        7
```

As you mentioned in the comment, this solution will still work if you can accept the order of price and stock is not consistent. Here is an example:

```
# Example
df

   name price_2 price_1 stock_2 stock_1 stock_11 price_11
1 main1       1       4       1       4        0        0
2 main2       3       2       3       2        2        2
3 main3       8       4       8       4        4        4
4 main4       3       7       3       7        7        7

# Solution
# Note that the order of stock and price is not consistent
df[, c(1, order(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]+", "", names(df)[-1]))) + 1)]

   name price_1 stock_1 price_2 stock_2 stock_11 price_11
1 main1       4       4       1       1        0        0
2 main2       2       2       3       3        2        2
3 main3       4       4       8       8        4        4
4 main4       7       7       3       3        7        7
```

Here is a way to work around that:

```
df1 <- df[c(names(df)[1], sort(names(df)[-1], decreasing=TRUE))]
df1[, c(1, order(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]+", "", names(df1)[-1]))) + 1)]

  name stock_1 price_1 stock_2 price_2 stock_11 price_11
 main1       4       4       1       1        0        0
 main2       2       2       3       3        2        2
 main3       4       4       8       8        4        4
 main4       7       7       3       3        7        7
```

Comment: thank you if works perfect. One question if it is simple is it possible to use it for column like stock_1 price_1 stock_2 price_2. I mean order based on the number and I know that the main part of colmuns are stock_ and price_?

Comment: Did you need to maintain the order for stock and price? For example, stock will be always after price.

Comment: Yes this is the order

Comment: If the original order is stock followed by price, it will still work. If the order changes sometimes, it'll be incorrect. But you can just order the column before the solution.

Comment: I just updated the answer. Please check whether it makes sense to you.